# Why cant we assign a variable in the `where` clause in parameterized view

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, variable-assignment

While I'm going through parameterized views, I've come across the following package and view which has deptno as parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE glb_variables
IS
  gv_deptno scott.emp.deptno%TYPE;

  PROCEDURE set_deptno(deptno_in scott.emp.deptno%TYPE);

  FUNCTION get_deptno RETURN scott.emp.deptno%TYPE;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY glb_variables
IS
  PROCEDURE set_deptno(deptno_in scott.emp.deptno%TYPE) IS
    BEGIN
      gv_deptno := deptno_in;
    END;

  FUNCTION get_deptno RETURN scott.emp.deptno%TYPE IS
    BEGIN
      RETURN gv_deptno;
    END;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW emp_in_dep AS
  SELECT *
  FROM scott.emp
  WHERE deptno = glb_variables.get_deptno;
```

In the `where` clause in the view, when I tried to assign directly the variable. I'm getting the following error.

`ORA-06553: PLS-221: 'GV_DEPTNO' is not a procedure or is undefined`

Why can't we assign a variable in the `where` clause?

Comment: Your function is wrapped in a package. So refer them as `where deptno = glb_variables.get_deptno();` I just added the braces at the end

Comment: I think you need to be clearer with your terminology. A `WHERE` clause defines a boolean test for filtering. You can't modify anything inside a `WHERE` clause. (Well, maybe with side effects, but if that works, it is so unpredictable you don't want to do that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worlds of PLSQL and SQL are close together but not that close. Package variables can not be used directly in SQL. You have to use a function that returns the value of that variable.